# Question is six years old, need updated answers

Tags: support

This [question](https://writers.stackexchange.com/q/2194/13494) is six years old.  I don't trust the answers, which were written by people who were waxing nostalgic about the past.

May I please just ask it again?  Or must I set a bounty to get fresh answers?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you need to specifically re-ask, but you can ask a different question altogether: Has standard manuscript format changed since 2011?

Comment: .....Brilliant.